# Which is faster for performance? htmlspecialchars or function?

Tags: php, performance, xss, htmlspecialchars

i'm looking to see which is faster?

I have a lot of users on the site at any given time and a lot of content to `echo` out.

Which would be faster?:

**case 1:**

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES);
```

**case 2:**

file 1:

```
function cleanText($string) {
    $newString = htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES);
    return $newString;
}

echo cleanText($_POST['name']);
```

Answer (score 1):

A few general thoughts:

- The case with the function is going to be very very slightly slower. It does the same thing as the non-function line, except a function needs to be called.
- The difference is so minuscule, that you should not worry about it. Calling functions is so fast that you should probably never make the trade-off of making less functions for the sake of speed.
- If your application ever feels like it's getting too slow, measure where it's slow and improve those things. Don't optimize before you need to.
- Many people these days don't call `htmlspecialchars` manually, but they will use a template engine instead. A template engine is much, much slower than calling this function. However, even though it's so much slower, it's still not slow enough for most people to actually care about this.